# acquire_lock stuck in Python's threads.Threading class?

Tags: python

I have a script that I launch on various remote hosts using Python Fabric's @parallel decorator.

The script runs on the remote hosts and runs FIO against various block devices in parallel.  The script uses the Python Threads class.

However, in some situations, the FIO tests are completed but the script hangs and never finishes the threading.Thread's join() ,method.

I took a backtrace of the script process, using 'gdb -p'.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  sem_wait () at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sem_wait.S:85
#1  0x0000000000547fa4 in PyThread_acquire_lock ()
#2  0x00000000005608ae in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000049968d in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#4  0x00000000004a090c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#5  0x0000000000499a52 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#6  0x00000000004a090c in PyEval_EvalCodeEx ()
#7  0x0000000000499a52 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#8  0x0000000000499ef2 in PyEval_EvalFrameEx ()
#9  0x00000000004a1634 in ?? ()
#10 0x000000000044e4a5 in PyRun_FileExFlags ()
#11 0x000000000044ec9f in PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags ()
#12 0x000000000044f904 in Py_Main ()
#13 0x00007f42c43faf45 in __libc_start_main (main=0x44f9c2 <main>, argc=5, argv=0x7fffd4e4bd48, init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, rtld_fini=<optimized out>, 
stack_end=0x7fffd4e4bd38) at libc-start.c:287
#14 0x0000000000578c4e in _start ()
```

Is this script stuck because of a lock problem in PyThread?